# PowerBI / SQL Query to verify records

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am working on a PowerBI report that is grabbing information from SQL and I cannot find a way to solve my problem using PowerBI or how to write the required code. My first table, Certifications, includes a list of certifications and required trainings that must be obtained in order to have an active certification.

My second table, UserCertifications, includes a list of UserIDs, certifications, and the trainings associated with a certification.

How can I write a SQL code or PowerBI measure to tell if a user has all required trainings for a certification? ie, if UserID 1 has the A certification, how can I verify that they have the TrainingIDs of 1, 10, and 150 associated with it?

Certifications:
[CertificationsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNomQ.png)

UserCertifications:
[UserCertificationsTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiYkQ.png)

Comment: I would start this by creating a table using DAX that lists certifications and the _count_ of training courses required. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarize-function-dax This is the "required certifications" count. Now you can work out "actual" certification count by person (probably using the same approach) and compare the two

Answer (score 0):

This is a DAX pattern to test if contains at least some values.

```
|       Certifications        |
|----------------|------------|
| Certification  | TrainingID |
|----------------|------------|
| A              | 1          |
| A              | 10         |
| A              | 150        |
| B              | 7          |
| B              | 9          |

|               UserCertifications              |
|--------------------|---------------|----------|
| UserID             | Certification | Training |
|--------------------|---------------|----------|
| 1                  | A             | 1        |
| 1                  | A             | 10       |
| 1                  | A             | 300      |
| 2                  | A             | 150      |
| 2                  | B             | 9        |
| 2                  | B             | 90       |
| 3                  | A             | 7        |
| 4                  | A             | 1        |
| 4                  | A             | 10       |
| 4                  | A             | 150      |
| 4                  | A             | 1000     |
```

In the above scenario, DAX needs to find out if the mandatory trainings `(Certifications[TrainingID])` by `Certifications[Certification]` is completed by
`UserCertifications[UserID ]`&&`UserCertifications[Certifications]` partition.

In the above scenario, DAX should only return true for `UserCertifications[UserID ]=4` as it is the only User that completed at least all the mandatory trainings.

The way to achieve this is through the following measure

```
areAllMandatoryTrainingCompleted = 
VAR _alreadyCompleted =
    CONCATENATEX (
        UserCertifications,
        UserCertifications[Training],
        "-",
        UserCertifications[Training]
    ) // what is completed in the fact Table; the fourth argument is very important as it decides the sort order
VAR _0 =
    MAX ( UserCertifications[Certification] )
VAR _supposedToComplete =
    CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER ( Certifications, Certifications[Certification] = _0 ),
        Certifications[TrainingID],
        "-",
        Certifications[TrainingID]
    ) // what is comeleted in the training Table; the fourth argument is very important as it decides the sort order
VAR _isMandatoryTrainingCompleted =
    CONTAINSSTRING ( _alreadyCompleted, _supposedToComplete ) // CONTAINSSTRING (<Within Text>,<Search Text>); return true false
RETURN
    _isMandatoryTrainingCompleted
```

[image: Solution]